# ERC20 Token paying ERC20 token -- this is not Inception

Tags: tokens

I'd like to know if the following can be implemented on the Ethereum platform:

I need users to be able to send a USD stable coin, eg TUSD, or DIA (which is an ERC20 token) to a smart contract address. This will keep some TUSD and send on some of the TUSD to another account; and it will record a holding and issue a token XXXX back to the sending account. Holders of the XXXX token will be able to call the smart contract and obtain TUSD (according to what they are owned, as stored in the SC).

I have seen SCs that pay dividends to token holders in Ether, but I need this to pay the token holders in an ERC20 token (TUSD, or DIA).

Is it possible?

Comment: I couldn't really follow your second paragraph, but yes, smart contracts can hold and transfer ERC20 tokens. (There's nothing special about this.)

Comment: And just to continue: you can't use (send/receive) any external coins in smart contracts, only Ethers and tokens created within the Ethereum blockchain.